# server socket reads object from one client and writes on other socket in java

Tags: java, serversocket

I want to develop a sever which do following tasks.
1)Accepts request from client1 reads objet and write another object
2)Accepts request from client2 reads objet and write another object
3)Client1 enters info of client2,server has to get the client2 based on info and write an object on client2

**Server java**

```
public class Server{
ServerSocket serverSocket ;
Socket socket;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static List<Map> clientList = new ArrayList<Map>();//creating list to store map objects of all clients


// Server socket instantiating
Server(int port) {
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//server is waiting on listen mode for accepting clients
void serverConnect() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server is Waiting for client to connect ");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            System.out.println("connected to: "+ socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            new Thread(new ClientSession(socket)).start();//creating a new thread for every client
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Server server = new Server(5050);
    try {
        server.serverConnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

ClientSession.java

```
`public class ClientSession implements Runnable {

Socket clientsocket;
String emailId;
String msg;
String ipaddress;
String phoneNumber;
String sessionId;
String socketAddress;
String calleeInfo;
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Server";
ObjectOutputStream oos;
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  Map globalmap = new HashMap();//creating a hashmap object to store sockets,objectoutputstreamobjects of clients

ClientSession(Socket socket) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    globalmap.put("clientsockets", socket);
    this.clientsocket = socket;
    System.out.println("socket--"+socket);
     try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
        globalmap.put("oos", oos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("A new Thread started");
    try {
        System.out.println("IN SERVER READ METHOD");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("map in servereread"+map);
        System.out.println("IN SERVER DECODE METHOD");
        msg =  map.get("msg");
        System.out.println(msg);
        emailId =  map.get("email");
        phoneNumber =  map.get("phoneno");
        globalmap.put("phoneno", phoneNumber);
        globalmap.put("email",emailId);
        Server.clientList.add(globalmap);
        if (msg.equals("REGISTER")) {
            System.out.println("IN DECODE REGISTER");
            ipaddress =  map.get("ipaddr");
        } else if (msg.equals("INVITE")) {
            System.out.println("IN DECODE INVITE");
            sessionId =  map.get("sessionId");
            calleeInfo =  map.get("calleeInfo");
        }
        analyze(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



private void analyze(Map<String, String> map) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        String SQL = null;
        System.out.println(msg);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"username","pwd");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        SocketAddress socketAddr = clientsocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
        socketAddress = socketAddr.toString();
        if (msg.equals("REGISTER")) {
            SQL = "INSERT INTO Register (email,phoneNumber,ipaddress,socketaddress) VALUES ('"+ emailId+ "','"+ phoneNumber+ "','"+ ipaddress+ "','" + socketAddress + "')";
            System.out.println("SQL statement..." + SQL);
            serverWrite();
        } else if (msg.equals("INVITE")) {
            System.out.println("Connecting to database for invite...");
            SQL = "INSERT INTO Invite (sessionid,calleremail,callerphoneNo,calleeInfo) VALUES ('"+ sessionId+ "','"+ emailId+ "','"+ phoneNumber+ "','" + calleeInfo + "')";
            System.out.println("SQL statement--" + SQL);
            System.out.println("CalleeInfo--" + calleeInfo);
            // Retrieve the socket of the destination
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Register WHERE email='"+ calleeInfo + "' OR phoneNumber = '" + calleeInfo+ "'";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("ResultSet--" + rs);
            if (rs.next()) {
                String socketaddr = rs.getString("socketaddress");
                String email= rs.getString("email");
                String phoneNo= rs.getString("phoneNumber");
                String ipadd= rs.getString("ipaddress");
            }
                for(int i=0;i<Server.clientList.size();i++){
                    String emailid= (String) Server.clientList.get(i).get("email");
                    String phone = (String) Server.clientList.get(i).get("phoneno");
                    if(calleeInfo.equals(emailid) || calleeInfo.equals(phone)){
                        ObjectOutputStream out1= (ObjectOutputStream) Server.clientList.get(i).get("oos");
                        System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream----"+out1);
                        System.out.println("writing on"+Server.clientList.get(i).get("clientsockets"));
                        System.out.println("map before writing on to client2--"+map);
                        out1.reset();
                        out1.writeObject(map);
                        out1.flush();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            // retrieve socket info from register table based on calleeInfo
            // as primary key
        }
        st.executeUpdate(SQL);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void serverWrite() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        // Using ObjectOutputStream class to write object
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();// Creating an object for HashMap class
          if (msg.equals("REGISTER")) {
            System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream storing--"+oos);
            map.put("msg", "REGISTERED"); // setting a message in HashMap object
            System.out.println("sending registered");
            oos.writeObject(map);// writing an object on socket
        } 
    /*  else if (msg.equals("INVITE")) {
            map.put("msg", "CALLING");
            System.out.println("sending calling");
        }*/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It is going to the client1 socket but its not writing on the client2..Its writing on client1..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the client not in the server in this case..but one suggestion is don't create map object as Map map= new Map;.It will take only Strings. just create as Map map=new Map();It will take Strings,arrays and all datatypes.